# How can use DataAnnotaions in webforms?

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations

I'm trying to use data annotation in my class to show in the `gridview`. But it isn't working for me.

```
class Customer
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode= true,DataFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime DateRecorded { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
gridview.DataSource = list of customer;
```

Comment: there is a good article and code sample here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/data-annotations-for-web-forms-in-net-4-5/

Comment: I'm using vs 4.0, and the link is in 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that It's not available in vs2010.

Answer (score 0):

it the better example for Data Annotaions with class diagrams check it this [***link***](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner)   and the other alternative [link with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)